# 'Is not a function' error in jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am working on a demo with a jquery carousel script and jScrollpane scrollbars with anchors links but I can't seem to get it working properly. Can someone point out what I am missing here in the script?

Via firebug I got the error messages:

*"Resuming debugger: error during debugging loop: TypeError: firstViewRangeElement is null"*

```
$(".scroll-pane-arrows").jScrollPane is not a function
```

**$('.scroll-pane-arrows').jScrollPane(my_jscrollpane_opts);** from: jquery.contentcarousel.js (line 272)

```
syntax error
```

**}** from: index.html (line 525)

Comment: Error messages aren't that useful without code to go with them.

Comment: can you point out exactly what you are missing? Probably using a screenshot? I fail to see the problem now :(

Comment: works ok on me, using chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: The demo doesn't work in ie, firefox and safari mac / pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling jScrollPane before you actually include its definition. If you view source in chrome

`view-source:http://members.chello.nl/j.bemmel2/carousel_/`

and look at line 512 - 518, you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
</script>
<!-- the Scrollbar script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

You are calling .contentcarousel() which calls jScrollPane, but without first including jscrollpane.min.js

What you should do is to have

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>`

prior to calling `.contentcarousel()`, as the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
<!-- the Scrollbar script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

also remove the comma `(,)` from below line (line no 524)

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
{
  hijackInternalLinks: true //remove comma from here
}
```

it will solve your error

```
syntax error
} from: index.html (line 525)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jquery version.

```
$ (Selector). Live (events, data, handler); / / jQuery 1.3 + 
$ (Document). Delegate (selector, events, data, handler); / / jQuery 1.4.3 + 
$ (Document). On (events, selector, data, handler); / / jQuery 1.7 + 

=> $ El.find ('a.ca-more'). Live ('click.contentcarousel', function (event) {
change $ (Document). On ('click', 'a.ca-more', function (event) {

=> $ el.find ('a.ca-close'). live ('click.contentcarousel', function (event) {
change $ (Document). On ('click', 'a.ca-close', function (event) {
```